# Copy Info from Specific Columns Within Active Row & Paste Into Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code which runs by the press of a macro button. It opens up a new doc based on a template and saves this new workbook as the address of the job which is held in column H of the first workbook in the active row. After this new workbook opens up, I want the information from specific columns along the original active row of the first workbook to be copied and pasted into the new workbook. I think the issue is that, once the code runs and opens up the new workbook, the active row is probably within that workbook. How can I write the code so it takes information from the original active row in the first workbook still? Any help greatly appreciated. See code below.

```
Sub CREATE_REINTSTATEMENT_SHEET()

'I want to open a new workbook from the reinstatement template
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim Loc As String
Dim FileSaveName As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim row As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
row = ActiveCell.row
Loc = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 8)
fPath = "filepath"

'I want this to save in a specific file location with the filename being the address taken from the planning sheet
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add("filepath.xlsx")
wb2.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & Loc & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52

'Next, copy info from planning sheet active row into reinstatement sheet
'To do this, i first have to set the planner sheet as the active workbook again
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
row = ActiveCell.row

'CLIENT
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 4).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 23).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'WI NO
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 5).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'POSTCODE
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 10).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'NED
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 7).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 23).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'AREA
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 9).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'FULL ADDRESS
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 8).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'DATE REQ
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 11).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'PUBLIC
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 24).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'MATERIAL
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 26).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'ROAD TYPE
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 27).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 13).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'LENGTH
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 29).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 14).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'WIDTH
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 30).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 15).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'DEPTH
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 31).Copy
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 16).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of workbook 1 showing the highlighted cells at the top to be copied (ignore bottom highlight)]
[image: screenshot of workbook 2, where info is going to be pasted]

Comment: You have twice `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` and `row = ActiveCell.Row`, so as FoxFire explained to you in your earlier question an hour ago, when you add a new workbook, that one is the active one so just delete the second time you have that particular code as you already have saved the necessary info. `wb2` is already your new workbook so no need to Set a new variable to it anyway.

Comment: I'm confused sorry, i know that the new workbook is my active one, i dont want it to be. I want to copy infomaton from the original workbook into the new workbook, by selecting information from the row i was originally in on the first workbook. I have tried both with and without including the setting the workbook twice and the result is the same. Its still considering the active row as in the new workbook but i want it to be the original active row

Comment: where i set 'row = ActiveCell.Row' at the beginning, i want it to then reference this same row again, but this is difficult as the active row will now be considered in the second workbook?

Comment: Just because you've given your row variable the ActiveCell.Row and then have a different ActiveCell later, doesn't mean that row variable got a different value. So just delete the second time you `Set wb =` and `row =` and you should be fine. Also, if you don't have leading numbers as text (with leading zeros for example), you don't need to use `.Copy`, you can just give the value to the new cell/range. `wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 23).Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 4).Value`

Comment: Thank you, someone had changed the sheet name and i hadn't realised so it wasn't pasting!

Comment: @LivHudson I strongly suggest to read [How to debug vba code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) so you can see step by step what is happening at every line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Values From the ActiveSheet to a New Template Workbook

```vb
Sub CreateReinstatementSheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DST_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const DST_TEMPLATE As String = "Template.xlsx"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    
    ' Build the Reinstatement template workbook path.
    
    Dim dTemplatePath As String: dTemplatePath = DST_FOLDER_PATH & DST_TEMPLATE
    
    ' Create a new workbook from the Reinstatement template workbook,
    ' the destination workbook.
    
    ' Reference the row of the active sheet, the source single-row range
    ' located on the Planning sheet.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ActiveCell.EntireRow
    
    ' Read the destination base name of the new workbook
    ' from the planning sheet...
    Dim dBaseName As String: dBaseName = srg.Columns("H").Value
    ' and build its path.
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = DST_FOLDER_PATH & dBaseName & ".xlsm"
    
    ' Open the template...
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(dTemplatePath)
    ' and save it as a macro-enabled workbook, the destination workbook.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Copy the values from the source range (Planning sheet)
    ' to the destination worksheet (Reinstatment sheet).
    
    With dwb.Worksheets(DST_SHEET)
        .Range("W5").Value = srg.Columns("D").Value 'CLIENT
        .Range("R5").Value = srg.Columns("E").Value 'WI NO
        .Range("W6").Value = srg.Columns("G").Value 'NED
        .Range("G6").Value = srg.Columns("H").Value 'FULL ADDRESS
        .Range("N5").Value = srg.Columns("I").Value 'AREA
        .Range("R6").Value = srg.Columns("J").Value 'POSTCODE
        .Range("G5").Value = srg.Columns("K").Value 'DATE REQ
        .Range("B10").Value = srg.Columns("X").Value 'PUBLIC
        .Range("K10").Value = srg.Columns("Z").Value 'MATERIAL
        .Range("M10").Value = srg.Columns("AA").Value 'ROAD TYPE
        .Range("N10").Value = srg.Columns("AC").Value 'LENGTH
        .Range("O10").Value = srg.Columns("AD").Value 'WIDTH
        .Range("P10").Value = srg.Columns("AE").Value 'DEPTH
    End With

'    ' Or if you insist on numbers, making it undreadable:
'    With dwb.Worksheets(DST_SHEET)
'        .Cells(5, 23).Value = srg.Cells(4).Value 'CLIENT
'        .Cells(5, 18).Value = srg.Cells(5).Value 'WI NO
'        .Cells(6, 23).Value = srg.Cells(7).Value 'NED
'        .Cells(6, 7).Value = srg.Cells(8).Value 'FULL ADDRESS
'        .Cells(5, 14).Value = srg.Cells(9).Value 'AREA
'        .Cells(6, 18).Value = srg.Cells(10).Value 'POSTCODE
'        .Cells(5, 7).Value = srg.Cells(11).Value 'DATE REQ
'        .Cells(10, 2).Value = srg.Cells(24).Value 'PUBLIC
'        .Cells(10, 11).Value = srg.Cells(26).Value 'MATERIAL
'        .Cells(10, 13).Value = srg.Cells(27).Value 'ROAD TYPE
'        .Cells(10, 14).Value = srg.Cells(29).Value 'LENGTH
'        .Cells(10, 15).Value = srg.Cells(30).Value 'WIDTH
'        .Cells(10, 16).Value = srg.Cells(31).Value 'DEPTH
'    End With

    ' Save and close it.
    
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Reinstatement workbook created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```